# Flask template rendering fail

Tags: flask, bootstrap-5, flask-wtforms

Since I changed from flask-boostrap to Boostrap-flask package I get the following error when I am rendering a template with a form in it:

```
...templates\bootstrap4\form.html", line 280, in template
    {%- for field in form %}
TypeError: 'TemplateModule' object is not iterable
```

What is weird is that I import Boostrap5(`from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap5`), but it loads Boostrap 4 html as you can see in the error message

This is how I import:

```
{% import 'bootstrap/form.html' as form %}
...
{{ form.render_form(form) }}
```

This is the form:

```
class TESTForm(FlaskForm):
    task = SelectMultipleField(label="Task")
    edit = SubmitField(label="Edit list")
    browser = SelectField(label='Select browser',choices=[('c','Chrome'),('e','Edge')])
    visible = RadioField(label="Show browser?",choices=[('y','Yes'),('n','No')],default='n')
    submit = SubmitField('Fill in')
```

Comment: You are using the sample variable name `form` for both your FlaskForm and the bootstrap-flask html.